# zabbix agent no network data - unless sudo

Tags: zabbix

I have been using Zabbix for about 2 weeks and think it's great.

My set up:
Server: Zabbix 2.2 Appliance
Clients: Ubuntu 12.04 Precise Server 64bit

I have installed the Zabbix agent (zabbix-agent_2.2.0-1+precise_amd64.deb ) using dpkg and normally after an hour - discovery populates more items for the servers and this includes Network interfaces and utilisation.

I have 1 server where this has not worked. All other data, CPU, memory, filesystems have come in but NOT network.

I have been trying to use the agent command to troubleshoot:

```
    $ zabbix_agentd -t "system.cpu.load[all,avg1]"
    system.cpu.load[all,avg1] [d|0.240000]
```

Where as the network fails:

```
    $ zabbix_agentd -t "net.if.in[eth0]"
    net.if.in[eth0] [m|ZBX_NOTSUPPORTED]
```

But if I run it as sudo it works...

```
    $ sudo zabbix_agentd -t "net.if.in[eth0]"
    [sudo] password for jsm:
    net.if.in[eth0] [u|27166807]
```

Do I have to change the permissions of something to get this working?

I've posted on the Zabbix forum - and no new ideas have come forward.  Thank you

*Further info on the host where this is happening:*
This 1 server is a little different. It is a hosted server, where you select the OS you want and they build it and send you root credentials to then use as you wish.

I have noticed on this server that ifconfig does not give the usual output, instead it replies with:
Warning: cannot open /proc/net/dev (No such file or directory). Limited output.

If I run sudo ifconfig then the output is normal:
eth0 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 00:1c:c0:ec:.....
etc

Other info on the server:
$ zabbix_agent -V
Zabbix agent v2.2.0 (revision 40163) (12 November 2013)
Compilation time: Nov 12 2013 12:23:06

$ sudo groups zabbix
zabbix : zabbix

$ sudo ls -als /proc/net/dev
0 -r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jan 28 11:48 /proc/net/dev

$lsb_release -irc
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Release: 12.04
Codename: precise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I did get this working by booting a non GRS kernel as described here.  Thanks Michael for the nudges.

http://neuro.me.uk/blog/2009/09/20/revert-to-standard-ubuntu-kernel-on-ovh-or-kimsufi-servers

Short version:

```
apt-get install linux-image-server
mkdir ~/ovh.d
mv /etc/grub.d/06_OVHkernel ~/ovh.d
update-grub
shutdown -r -f now
```

And now the stats come through fine.

Answer (score 1):

I you don't want to change your kernel :

Create a new script directory :

```
mkdir /etc/zabbix/root
chown root.zabbix /etc/zabbix/root
chmod 750 /etc/zabbix/root
```

Add this line to /etc/sudoers :

```
zabbix  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /etc/zabbix/root/*.sh
```

Create /etc/zabbix/root/net-if-in.sh :

```
 cat /proc/net/dev | grep $INTERFACE |  awk '{ print $2; }'
```

Create /etc/zabbix/root/net-if-out.sh :

```
 cat /proc/net/dev | grep $INTERFACE |  awk '{ print $10; }'
```

Add this 2 lines to zabbix_agentd.conf :

```
UserParameter=net-if-in[*], sudo /etc/zabbix/root/net-if-in.sh $1
UserParameter=net-if-out[*], sudo /etc/zabbix/root/net-if-out.sh $1
```

Test it :

```
sudo -u zabbix zabbix_agentd -t "net-if-in[eth0]"
```

Restart the agent, add the new items in zabbix server !

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with zabbix as you can clearly see. This is a "problem" with the server and not even with the "OS" but with the platform. What you describe seems to be some pseudo virtualization container like OpenVZ or some weird kernel patch. I try my best to avoid these so can't advice anything specific. But start from getting the information about the platform.

Edit: the "weird patch" appears to be the grsecurity.

Comment: I agree that this is an OS issue.  Unfortunately the budget hosting company this server runs on do not offer support ... you have to fix things for yourself.  So far no one in the Zabbix forum has been able to answer ... I was hoping someone here would have come across this and can advise what I can do... surely if the data is available when I run as sudo then it should be a matter of changing settings... thanks anyway

Comment: start from checking for grsecurity, see if /proc/sys/kernel/grsecurity is there. show us `uname -a`

Comment: Thanks Michael.  The output from uname -a is:    Linux ns3097402.ip-91-zzz-zzz.eu 3.10.23-xxxx-grs-ipv6-64 #1 SMP Mon Dec 9 19:06:18 CET 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux.  And the directory "/proc/sys/kernel/grsecurity/" does exist

Comment: well, this seems like OVH. and -grs- is exactly that. the grsecurity patch. search how to disable access restrictions to the dev/net

Comment: I've been busy for a few days, but I think the answer lies here:
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Grsecurity/Appendix/Grsecurity_and_PaX_Configuration_Options#Default_Special_Groups

GRKERNSEC_PROC_GID
Setting this GID determines which group will be exempted from
grsecurity's /proc restrictions, allowing users of the specified
group  to view network statistics and the existence of other users'
processes on the system.  This GID may also be chosen at boot time
via "grsec_proc_gid=" on the kernel commandline.

I'll test it and come back...

Comment: I edited /etc/default/grub and added the "grsec_proc_gid=110"... & rebooted, so now ~$ cat /proc/cmdline
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/bzImage-3.10.23-xxxx-grs-ipv6-64 root=/dev/sda1 ro grsec_proc_gid=110
However it still hasn't worked ... any inspirations pls let me know & thanks for reading

Comment: @user3223819 does it work with grsecurity disabled? Try to boot a non grs kernel. If my guess was right and you are on ovh, then your kernels are here: ftp://ftp.ovh.net/made-in-ovh/bzImage/3.10.23